# Cannot include json file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to use svg and node graph but I cannot seem to manage to include the json file for drawing the nodes and the link.

Here is the code I use (straight from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/950642/):

```
  d3.json("graph.json", function (error, json) {
        force
            .nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .start();
```

If I embed the json file in my document an uncomment the first line (and the ending }) it works fine.

I have the d3.js file locally (works also when I read from another server). I haven't tried to use the javascript console.
The graph.json is in the same directory than my html file. I am running on IIS Express (same problem on regular IIS)

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?
TIA

Comment: Did you copy [graph.json](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/950642/graph.json) onto your *own* server into the directory of the script?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... Have you installed the D3.js library? Are you using a web server? Have you checked the JavaScript console?

Comment: Like Alvaro my first guess would be that you're not using a web server. However, have you tried `console.log(error)` or `console.log(json)` to see what's going on.

Comment: Thx, I will try your suggestions and let you know...